# When Using startActivityForResult(), How Can You Prevent The Device From Saving The Image To The Phone's Gallery?

Tags: android

```
public void openCameraLog(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

When this code is run, the image that is captured through the camera is automatically saved to the phone's gallery.

Comment: That is by incidence. Most camera apps will only deliver you an thumbnail in onActivityResult. Try other camera apps and devices.

Comment: You can create an image `Uri` first and fill in data by using `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)`, and any time you don't that image file you can just delete this `imageUri`. Check out my demo: https://youtu.be/tPwr2yYxlA4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found that using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

will save the result (the image captured) into the gallery/photos app on most devices. To fix this problem, you can use the [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) API.